# How should CORS work and is Spring Boot doing the right thing?

Tags: spring-boot, cors, jersey

First, please correct my understanding of the CORS mechanism.

At a very high level, my understanding is that

1. request with `Origin` header and url value of `http://example.com` is sent
2. If origin is one of the whitelisted, then a successful response with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`:`http://example.com` header is returned
3. If origin is not one of the whitelisted, then a 403 Forbidden returns

Diving a little deeper, I'd like to know what exactly sets the header and what exactly throws 403.

Is it the case that

1. **Browser** automatically sets the `Origin` header
2. If origin is not whitelisted, then a successful response is returned anyways, just without the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header
3. Then **Browser** converts the missing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` into a 403

Or is it the case that

1. **Browser** automatically sets the `Origin` header
2. **Server** sees that origin is not on whitelist, and returns a 403 response

So my questions is

> Who's responsible for generating the 403? Browser in scenario 1 above or Server in scenario 2 above?

I ask because in Jersey world, we have an implementation that seems to follow scenario 1 above. But in Spring Boot world, Cors seems to follow scenario 2.

**EDIT**

From comments below, it sounds like Spring Boot is doing more than it needs to by throwing a 403. Now my new question is, is there a way to prevent Spring Boot from throwing automatically returning 403 if the origin is not in the whitelist, but instead just not set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as the CORS protocol defines

Comment: The step 1 items (browser sends the Origin header) in the lists in the question are the only statements in the question that describe standard behavior defined in the CORS protocol. The step 2 items (server checks a whitelist) are not required or defined by the CORS protocol. Instead as far as the CORS protocol is concerned, the server can either send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header, or not send — whichever the server chooses to do, for whatever reason — and the server can set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header to whatever origin value it wants, or to `*`.

Comment: A 403 response is not a standard part of the CORS protocol at all. A server can respond with a 403 whenever it wants to, for whatever reason. And the CORS specification doesn’t define any case where servers are required to respond with a 403. The only part of what’s described in the question which is actually defined by the CORS specification is the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header.

Comment: And to be clear about one thing: The browser definitely never converts a missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin header into a 403. 403 is an HTTP *response* code— and all HTTP response code are issued by servers, not browsers. There are no circumstances under which a browser itself issues a 403 response— not as part of CORS nor as part of any other standard protocol. It’s up to servers to return whatever response codes they want to, for whatever reason. So when you see a 403 or any other HTTP response code in a browser, the browser is just passing on as-is whatever response code the server sent.

Comment: It sound like Spring Boot is doing something extra that it doesn't need to then, by returning a 403.

Comment: Yeah the reason it’s not necessary to send a 403 in this case is that the presence or absence of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header, and the Access-Control-Allow-Origin value, are sufficient for conveying to browsers that browsers shouldn’t allow access to the response. A 403 response code doesn’t cause anything additional to happen beyond what the browser’s own handling of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header would. That’s why a 200 OK success response is appropriate and sufficient: It just means, *The request was received, and we’re sending a response for the client to handle*

Comment: But while the CORS requirements don’t mandate servers must respond with a 403 when receiving requests from origins they don’t want to allow, the requirements also don’t explicitly prohibit servers from responding with a 403 in that case if they want to. Whether it’s a good idea to send a 403 in that case is debatable. I guess the people who wrote the Spring CORS code judged it to be a good idea. But the majority of other CORS libraries for other server runtimes don’t send a 403 in that case— instead they just send a 200 OK with/without the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. And that works.

Comment: Sending a 403 rather the response payload with a 200 seems like a good idea in general to prevent data leaking from the server. I suppose the browser will prevent the data from being used but it still gets sent and received. But I believe you're right and now I have to stop Spring Boot from sending 403's to preserve an existing behavior

Comment: Well it seems the safe way to prevent data leaking would be to use some form of authentication. The thing is, an Origin header value can be trivially spoofed using curl or any other non-browser client. So without some kind of authentication — I mean beyond CORS, which isn’t strictly about authentication — anybody can just use curl or whatever to exfiltrate data not intended for them, simply by sending a request with a spoofed Origin header. So anyway, CORS isn’t intended as an authentication means per se — instead it’s intended to prevent privilege escalation and confused-deputy attacks.

Comment: I'm curious what in the Jersey world you are referring to, as there is no standard CORS support in Jersey.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Someone on my team implemented Jersey CORS support as a `ContainerResponseFilter`. But Spring Boot offers CORS support out of the box and has this behavior of returning 403, that's why I was questioning our Jersey implementation.

Comment: I've work with a few different (Java) frameworks and I think all of them I've worked with actually return 403 in cases of failed CORS requests. For instance, [RestEasy CorsFilter](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/d6fc3ea41014e88d4c296c7d985df956923886dc/resteasy-core/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/interceptors/CorsFilter.java#L198) throws ForbiddenException (maps to 403) when the Origin check fails.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha I appreciate the additional data point. I will have to discuss with my team whether we want to support the most basic requirements of CORS or follow what seems to be industry standard in practice.

Answer (score -1):

SpringBoot follows it's own implementation in sending a `403` to an OPTIONS request when origin doesn't match.

[DefaultCorsProcessor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/cors/DefaultCorsProcessor.java#L106)

> The default implementation sets the response status to 403 and writes
> "Invalid CORS request" to the response.